# Using System.Linq.Async.ToAsyncEnumerable with SignalR and MessagePack

Tags: c#, signalr, msgpack

I've been experimenting with SignalR streaming, and I've run across a problem (albeit with a workaround), but I wonder if there's anything I can do to make this work.

I'm trying to send a SignalR request with a large amount of data, so switched to using streaming to allow a potentially large collection to be sent in the request.  This collection is a simple IEnumerable of objects.

In the implementation, I'm converting from that IEnumerable to an IAsyncEnumerable of contract DTO objects instead.

I started trying to use ToAsyncEnumerable to do this:

```
var dtoItems = items.Select(i => i.ToContract()).ToAsyncEnumerable();

var result = await this.connection.InvokeAsync<DTO.Result>("RequestName", dtoItems).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, when I try this, I get the following exception:

```
MessagePack.Internal.MessagePackDynamicObjectResolverException: can't find matched constructor. type:System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+AsyncIListEnumerableAdapter`1[<ItemIdentity type>]
```

(ItemIdentity type replaces my internal type name)

I suspect it's something to do with the internal object not being available for serialization.

If I use a yield return loop, it works:

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<DTO.ItemIdentity> DtoItems()
{
    foreach (var i in items)
    {
        yield return i.ToContract();
    }
}
```

Is using ToAsyncEnumerable for SignalR MessagePack streaming possible - am I missing something, or should I give up?

I've been asked for a clearer example, so hopefully this will help!

The method that calls InvokeAsync is an implemetation of an interface that takes an IEnumerable of objects that are from an abstraction model.  These are then converted to DTO objects that are then sent over the wire.  This is to decouple the abstraction from the concrete SignalR implementation.

```
public virtual async Task<Model.RegisterResult> RegisterAsync(IEnumerable<Model.ItemIdentity> items, bool requireCapabilities, bool registerOnly)
{
    var dtoItems = items.Select(i => i.ToContract()).ToAsyncEnumerable();

    async IAsyncEnumerable<DTO.ItemIdentity> DtoItems()
    {
        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            yield return i.ToContract();
        }
    }

    // Replace dtoItems with DtoItems() to use the 'yield return' mechanism of generating an IAsyncEnumerable
    var result = await this.connection.InvokeAsync<DTO.RegisterResult>("RegisterAsync", dtoItems, requireCapabilities, registerOnly).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return result.FromContract();
}

...

// Type conversion extension method
public static DTO.ItemIdentity ToContract(this Model.ItemIdentity item)
{
    var dtoItem = new DTO.ItemIdentity();
    // Performs conversion work in here
    return dtoItem;
}
```

Note that as part of this work my library is transitioning from 1.x to 2.x, so I have plenty of scope to make breaking changes, such as making the abstraction interface method accept IAsyncEnumerable if that will improve performance.  I've not got that far yet - I'm still in the investigation stage.

Comment: This is a method that takes an IEnumerable of an abstraction model object, ToContract is an extension method that converts it to a DTO object which I then send using InvokeAsync.

(hit return too soon - I'll add more info to the question!)

Comment: There is, as in this case, the IEnumerable can contain many items (up to around 50000 or possibly more).  If this is just IEnumerable, then the SignalR message buffer will have to be sized big enough to accept this in a single request.  The reason I moved to this is because I was blowing out the default buffer with only around 500 items.  Using IAsyncEnumerable allows SignalR streaming, which allows much larger requests.

Comment: Ahh ok, Your question is clearer now.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the SignalR library. Although it is probably more efficient to make the IAsyncEnumerable the second way (also pass `items` to the `DtoItems` function instead of capturing it to avoid an allocation).

Comment: I'll leave this for a little while, but I suspect I'll just have to close it as a bug.  Thanks for your comment, much appreciated!